# Python JSON / Dict search and value updates

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a bunch of data entries that look as follows:

```
{'formType': 'tax', 'periodEndDate': '2016-03-31', 'periodStartDate': 'NULL', 'fiscalYearEnd': 2016, 'label': 'FY2016'}
{'formType': 'tax', 'periodEndDate': '2015-03-31', 'periodStartDate': 'NULL', 'fiscalYearEnd': 2015, 'label': 'FY2015'}
{'formType': 'tax', 'periodEndDate': '2014-03-31', 'periodStartDate': 'NULL', 'fiscalYearEnd': 2014, 'label': 'FY2014'}
{'formType': 'amend', 'periodEndDate': '2015-06-30', 'periodStartDate': 'NULL', 'fiscalYearEnd': 'NULL', 'label': 'NULL'}
{'formType': 'amend', 'periodEndDate': '2015-09-30', 'periodStartDate': 'NULL', 'fiscalYearEnd': 'NULL', 'label': 'NULL'}
{'formType': 'amend', 'periodEndDate': '2014-06-30', 'periodStartDate': 'NULL', 'fiscalYearEnd': 'NULL', 'label': 'NULL'}
{'formType': 'amend', 'periodEndDate': '2014-09-30', 'periodStartDate': 'NULL', 'fiscalYearEnd': 'NULL', 'label': 'NULL'}
```

I want to search through this data and set the 'periodStartDate' value to the date one day after the prior period's entry for 'periodEndDate' (of the same formType). I'm comfortable using datetime and the date additions, etc, but I am not sure how to cross-reference the different line items in this file to extrapolate the periodStartDate.

Also, the 'formType':'amend' needs to set its 'fiscalYearEnd' value based on using the year that its wedged between from the above 'formType':'tax' key-value pairs.

Comment: is it list of dicts? Also show the expected result

Comment: Yes, its a list of dicts. I want to be able to search the entire document by key:value and return the value, using any key.
For example, "find row with fiscalYearEnd = 2015 and return that row's periodEndDate (or whatever)". I am also open to other data structures if a list of dicts is confusing. I chose this format only because it looks similar to json which is how i plan to ultimately export and store it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would import each line into a `list of dicts` then iterate over that list to get the result you want using `datetime.timedelta`

I converted the dicts you provided into a list to simulate my example.

```
import datetime

list_of_dicts =[
                {'formType': 'tax', 'periodEndDate': '2016-03-31', 'periodStartDate': 'NULL', 'fiscalYearEnd': 2016, 'label': 'FY2016'},
                {'formType': 'tax', 'periodEndDate': '2015-03-31', 'periodStartDate': 'NULL', 'fiscalYearEnd': 2015, 'label': 'FY2015'},
                {'formType': 'tax', 'periodEndDate': '2014-03-31', 'periodStartDate': 'NULL', 'fiscalYearEnd': 2014, 'label': 'FY2014'},
                {'formType': 'amend', 'periodEndDate': '2015-06-30', 'periodStartDate': 'NULL', 'fiscalYearEnd': 'NULL', 'label': 'NULL'},
                {'formType': 'amend', 'periodEndDate': '2015-09-30', 'periodStartDate': 'NULL', 'fiscalYearEnd': 'NULL', 'label': 'NULL'},
                {'formType': 'amend', 'periodEndDate': '2014-06-30', 'periodStartDate': 'NULL', 'fiscalYearEnd': 'NULL', 'label': 'NULL'},
                {'formType': 'amend', 'periodEndDate': '2014-09-30', 'periodStartDate': 'NULL', 'fiscalYearEnd': 'NULL', 'label': 'NULL'}
                ]

def searchForYear(year):
    for subdict in list_of_dicts:
        if str(year) == 'NULL':
            print ("Year is NULL")
        elif str(year) == str(subdict['fiscalYearEnd']):
            if input('Do you want update this row? ') == 'yes':
                EndDate = datetime.datetime.strptime((subdict['periodEndDate']),"%Y-%m-%d").date()
                StartDate = EndDate + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
                subdict['periodStartDate'] = StartDate
                print ("StartDate is now ",subdict['periodStartDate'])
            else:
                print ("Did not update")

        else:
            print ("Year does not appear in this row")


submitYear = input("Check and update Year: ")
searchForYear(submitYear)
```

The result should be something like:

```
Check and update Year: 2016
Do you want update this row? yes
StartDate is now  2016-04-01
Year does not appear in this row
Year does not appear in this row
Year does not appear in this row
Year does not appear in this row
Year does not appear in this row
Year does not appear in this row
```

Comment: @JackBurton: Sorry about all the edits. I was messing around with it to get everything working the way I thought you needed. Let me know if this helped.

Comment: @JackBurton: Be sure to select the check mark next to the answer if it resolved your problem. This will help other find the answer they need if they find this post in relation to one of their own problems :)

Comment: Thanks - it looks like this code sets the StartDate based on the same dict's EndDate. I want to be able to search the entire list of dicts by, say, 'fiscalYearEnd', then return the row/dict's EndDate value that matches the fiscalYearEnd search value, and then use that EndDate to set the StartDate of my row.

Comment: @JackBurton: Ahhh I see. Well I am out of time at work right now so about to head home. If no one has answered your question by the time I get home I will review my answer and try to answer the question again :)